# PHP Image to Color-able image using GDLib

Tags: php, image-processing, gdlib

I am currently working on a **PHP** script to build a coloring book. User will upload the images(colored) and I've convert those images into colorless images(Color-able) and arrange them in a PDF file. Everything is managed but I am not able to convert image into the color-able image. Image show have white background and black strokes.

Currently I am using this code:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);
/* R, G, B, so 0, 255, 0 is green */

if ($im) {
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_MEAN_REMOVAL);
    imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);
    imagejpeg($im, "tmp_image/image-".$i.".jpg");
    $pdf_images[] = "tmp_image/image-".$i.".jpg";
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

For example:
[Color Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kk2MP.png)
to
[Color-able Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl0oP.jpg)

**Thank you for the help.**

I tried the PHP GDLib Edge Detection filter but couldn't get the required result.

Comment: You need to provide code, and let us know the errors you are having so we can help

Comment: Hi Thanks.
I am using this code.

`$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            /* R, G, B, so 0, 255, 0 is green */
            if($im)
            {
                imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
                imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
                imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_MEAN_REMOVAL);
                imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_CONTRAST, -1000);
                imagejpeg($im, "tmp_image/image-".$i.".jpg");
                $pdf_images[] = "tmp_image/image-".$i.".jpg";
                imagedestroy($im);
            }`

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. You supply 2 images. I presume the first one is what you start with and the second one is what you want to end up with. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yeah you're correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are filtering or doing edge detection if your image is already stroked in black? Surely you just want to make everything that is:

- either transparent, or
- not black

all turn into white.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php

$img  = imagecreatefrompng('apple.png');
$w = imagesx($img);
$h = imagesy($img);

// Create a new palettised colorable image same size
// We only need 2 colours so palettised will be fine and nice and small
$colorable = imagecreate($w,$h);
$white = imagecolorallocate($colorable,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($colorable,0,0,0);

for($x=0;$x<=$w;$x++){
    for($y=0;$y<=$h;$y++){
        $px = imagecolorsforindex($img,imagecolorat($img,$x,$y));
        // Assume we will make this pixel black in new image
        $newcolour = $black;
        $R = $px['red']; $G = $px['green']; $B = $px['blue']; $A = $px['alpha'];

        // If this pixel is transparent, or has any significant red, green or blue component, make it white
        if(($A==127) || ($R > 80) || ($G > 80) || ($B > 80)){
            $newcolour = $white;
        }
        imagesetpixel($colorable,$x,$y,$newcolour);
    }
}
imagepng($colorable,'result.png');
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is pretty hard, I dont know if this will work on all images but this will help get you on your way:

```
<?php

$image_name = 'apple.png';

$img = imagecreatefrompng ( $image_name );
$size = getimagesize( $image_name );

if( $img ){ 
    $new_image = colourable( $img , $size );
}

function colourable( $img , $size ) {

    $new_img = imagecreate( $size[0] , $size[1] );
    $white = imagecolorallocate( $new_img , 255 , 255 , 255 );
    imagefill( $new_img , 0 , 0 , $white );

    $black = imagecolorallocate( $new_img , 0 , 0 , 0 );

    for( $x = 0; $x <= ( $size[0] - 1 ); $x++ ){
        for( $y = 0; $y <= ( $size[1] - 1 ); $y++ ){
            $pixel = imagecolorsforindex( $img, imagecolorat ( $img , $x , $y ) );
            if( ( $pixel['red'] >= 0 &&  $pixel['red'] < 50 ) && ( $pixel['green'] >= 0 && $pixel['green'] < 50 ) && ( $pixel['blue'] >= 0 && $pixel['blue'] < 50 ) ){
                imagesetpixel( $new_img , $x , $y , $black );
            }               
        }
    }
    return $new_img;
}

header ( 'Content-Type: image/png' );
imagepng( $new_image );

?>
```

This is the result from the supplied image: 
[image]

It also worked with a few other images, some good some not so good but play around with it and see what you can do. It's pretty self explanatory but it basically grabs the colour of each pixel within the image and checks if it falls within the RGB code of black with some tolerance. (black being 0, 0, 0). It could be fine tuned.

It checks if:
RED &
GREEN &
BLUE 
all fall between 0 and 50 on the rgb scale.

```
if( ( $pixel['red'] >= 0 &&  $pixel['red'] < 50 ) && ( $pixel['green'] >= 0 && $pixel['green'] < 50 ) && ( $pixel['blue'] >= 0 && $pixel['blue'] < 50 ) ){
```

Comment: Hi there glad that you answered.
It's amazing. But the only thing I wanna ask can you convert that black background to white leaving a store to shape the apple?
Thanks man!

Comment: I think you'd need to play around with some of the settings, it'd take some thinking. Problem is every image changes so you have to detect it some how. If I couldn't find anything to handle this like a php library I would count the black pixels after running this function.  If there is more then you can almost (being keyword here) guarantee that it has a black background. From there I could running a similar function creating a new image, when it finds a white pixel, I'd add black pixels to make the boarder. Not sure if this would work or what it would look like.